# Devtools not installing, non-zero exit status

Tags: r, devtools

I'm very new to R and I've been trying to install CRAN "devtools" package in R, version 4.1.2 and keep getting the following error message (I am on a Windows 11 computer, 64-bit):

```
> install.packages("devtools")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/court/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
There is a binary version available but the source version is later:  
installing the source package ‘devtools’ 
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devtools_2.4.5.tar.gz' 
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 374718 bytes (365 KB) downloaded 365 KB 
* installing *source* package 'devtools' ... 
** package 'devtools' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked ** 
using staged installation ** R ** inst ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading 
Warning message: package 'usethis' was built under R version 4.1.3 
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : namespace 'htmltools' 0.5.2 is being loaded, but >= 0.5.4 is required 
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace 
Execution halted 
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'devtools' * removing 'C:/Users/court/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/devtools' 
Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status The downloaded source packages are in ‘C:\Users\court\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSGwqVR\downloaded_packages’
```

Does anyone have any input about how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

I installed the rtools package relevant to my computer but that didn't work. I also ran RStudio as an administrator and it didn't work either.

Comment: You need to update your version of R to 4.2.2 (note this is not related to Rstudio)

Comment: The error message tells you that the issue lies with the package `htmltools`. Quit R, restart, update the existing packages, check that the version of `htmltools` is >= 0.5.4 and try again. You don't need Rtools unless you answered "Yes" when asked if you want to install from source.